# Odd matrix notation: $||\mathbf{A}||$

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

My friend was reading the text for her engineering class, and came across the symbol $||\mathbf{A}||$, where $\mathbf{A}$ is a matrix. My guess is that it is a determinant, but it is essentially without context, and the book is expecting the students have a strong background in linear algebra.

I know there is such a thing as matrix magnitude; is this usually how it is denoted? Are there other things which are commonly represented this way?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm

Comment: That is pretty standard for matrix magnitude (norm).

Comment: Viewing the set of $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) as a linear space, it has lots of norms.  It seems impossible to give a good answer from the information you've given.  You say that $||A||$ appears "essentially without context": so it's just floating there in the middle of the page?  I think you should try a little harder to give some context: e.g. what is the text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be a determinant, but more likely it is a [matrix norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) (in particular engineering rings a bell as it could relate to some numerical analysis; but I don't know of course for sure).

Comment: It could be the absolute value of the determinant... But writing that instead of $|\det A|$ would be a rather poor choice of notation.